# Laravel SQLSTATE[HY093] with array query

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

I make a query as below

```
$lessonIDs = DB::table($personType."_has_lesson")->where("id",$userID)->pluck("lesson_id");
$lessons = DB::table("lesson")->where("lesson_id",$lessonIDs)->get();
```

value of `lessonIDs` is `["EEZ401","EEZ02","EEZ403"]`

I know we can make query with array on Laravel but it returns `SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined (SQL: select * from "lesson" where "lesson_id" = EEZ401)`. I made some research and I found that is a [bug](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/issues/4213) on laravel then I updated the project by `composer update` but nothing changed.

- Database is postgresql
- Laravel version is 9.10.1

Comment: I think the method you are looking for is `whereIn`. `->whereIn("lesson_id",$lessonIDs)->get();` Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#additional-where-clauses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where condition doesn't supports Arrays than you have to use **WhereIn** condition

```
$lessonIDs = DB::table($personType."_has_lesson")->where("id",$userID)->pluck("lesson_id");
$lessons = DB::table("lesson")->whereIn("lesson_id",$lessonIDs)->get();
```